# How do I Post PDF Form Field Data from inside a PDF via code?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, adobe

I have PDF that opens in a browser (iframe) that has standard PDF form fields.  I would like the user to fill out all the fields and then press an HTML submit button (located outside the iframe in the surrounding ASPX page) so that all the data in the PDF that was filled out in the PDF Form Fields posts that to another ASPX page.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to follow recommended path: add submit button to your PDF form (not surrounding ASPX page).

The button should submit to another ASPX page. That (second) ASPX page should parse submitted PDF/FDF/XFDF itself or with help of a library.

Comment: That's how we do it now.  However, ever since Google Chrome released it's native PDF viewer, it "broke the internet" and the PDF submit buttons will not submit from their viewer.

Comment: Wow! Didn't know that. AFAIK, PDF Viewer plugin does not provide an automation API and so there is no way to access loaded PDF from outside. I can only think of creating HTML forms for Chrome users on the fly but it's not very convenient.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we've done as an alternative for Adobe Reader issues for a few years now but a lot of our customers want to be able just upload unique PDFs with form fields for their clients to fill out so creating an HTML version on the fly is a pretty involved process to create.  Thanks for your time though!

Comment: Sounds like you need to detect Chrome and say "use Reader or it won't work".